# Passing large amounts of data in an WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I've seen this question pop up a few times but with no real definitive answer (as there is most likely none)... I have a WCF service that needs to return approximately 14,000 rows of data from SQL sorted in an List<> based array.

My service config looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IParts" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

My client config looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IParts" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/RasFuseService/Parts.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IParts"
            contract="MyParts.IParts" name="BasicHttpBinding_IParts" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Something isn't right because i'm getting the error:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: 
>       There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter     http://tempuri.org/:GetSurplusECMResult. 
>       The InnerException message was 'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or   deserialized in an object graph is '65536'. 
>       Change the object graph or increase the MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota. '.  Please see   InnerException for more details.

Even though i'm explicitly assigning MaxItemsInObjectGraph with a max int...

I've read about streaming and paging, but is this really too much data to return in a single pass?

Comment: Think about it from a users perspective am I really going to very more than 200 rows of data at a time?  The answer is most likely no.

Comment: The data returned is what was required by design... This company wants to know what was sold between (x) and (x) dates...

Comment: <behaviors>

<behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">

<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />

</behavior>

</behaviors>

Note that you also have to do this on the client. See here (scroll down for answer): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c85f3ed2-0b55-4375-af79-5926b6cc527c/

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv, it is and i posted it above...

Comment: does it have to be transfered in one message?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, it would be preferred... I've thought of getting X records per call, but i'd rather not.

Comment: which .NET version do you use for this assembly? if below 4.0 ... try adding behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" to the endpoints attributes

Comment: forget about that ... add a services section and define the service ... add behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" to the services attributes

Comment: i'm using 4.0. I tried that and it is still giving the same exception... almost likes it's ignoring the maxItemsInObjectGraph property i set...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out (*Slapped forehead*)
I ended up writing an incorrect entry on the client side. The correct syntax for the client side should have been:

```
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior >
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

Not

```
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

It now returns and deserializes my large array without complaining...

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where my WCF service returned raw tabular data, a few megabytes at a time.

The XML serialization was bad... lots of elements and wasted space, and also slow. I handled my own response generation in this case and returned data formatted as CSV data. It was considerably faster, both to generate, send, and parse by the client.

I was using REStful WCF (this was before ASP.NET replaced WCF for REST), so I just returned a Stream from my WCF method.

Answer (score 0):

In your client config your behaviour has a name, but you don't seem to use that name. Either use the name somewhere or omit the name to make your behaviour the default behaviour as in the service config.